# RabbitMQ - How to setup dead letter queue to autodelete?

Tags: rabbitmq, ttl, dead-letter

Is there posibility to setup RabbitMQ dead-letter queue to auto-deleteing itself when has no waiting messages to re-deliever?

I have dead-letter queue with arguments:

```
x-message-ttl: 15000
x-dead-letter-exchange: default-exchange
x-dead-letter-routing-key: main-queue
durable: true
```

`auto_delete` - doesn't work, because DL queue has no consumer

`x-expires` - kills DL queue at expired specific time, and cancel messages in queue as well (I don't want to lost them)